# How can i set a value to Bulk insert parameter?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm write this code for run the sql server script with c#:

```
string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=SERVERRAREPORT;Integrated Security=True";
            //string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=True";
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo("d:\\behzadBULK.sql");
            string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
            Microsoft.SqlServer.Server server = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
            server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
```

and into the `behzadBULK.sql` i write this code:

```
BULK INSERT TEMPO
FROM 'd:\3.csv'
WITH(
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
    CODEPAGE = '1256'
  );
```

into the Bulk insert ,From parameter set off the file name,that parameter is static,but i want in c# application browse file with browser and select file and set file name to bulk insert from parameter.

my plan is this:
[image]

Comment: Your code snippet shows horizontal scrollbars and is hard to read. Please edit.

Comment: give your stored procedure a parameter which takes the path of the file and pass it into the bulk insert

Comment: @MihaiTibrea please post your solution.thanks.

Comment: @MihaiTibrea my bulk insert save into the a file and file on the my hard drive

Comment: @behzadrazzaqi next time, do a little research, don't ask us to give you the answer without putting in any effort ! and please format your code, it's unreadable !

Comment: @MihaiTibrea okay okay my friend,please wait,i'm now test your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the structure of a bulk insert :

```
BULK INSERT 
   [ database_name. [ schema_name ] . | schema_name. ] [ table_name | view_name ] 
  FROM 'data_file' 
 [ WITH ...
```

Because the filename must be static you can do the following:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000) = 'BULK INSERT TEMPO FROM ''' + @FileName + ''' WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR ='','', ROWTERMINATOR =''\n'' )';
EXEC(@sql);
```